# Audio Streaming on Alexa

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

How to write intents for streaming audio from url in Alexa ?

What changes or functions do I need to write in lambda function for streaming audio url in alexa.

I have gone through AWS blogs but not able to implement this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm working on Alexa skill that can play audio. This [link](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player) helped me a lot to start. I guess, it'll answer your questions

Comment: yeah that is fine there also didn't mentioned anywhere how to run this, poor documentation